# issues with GDB and Yosemite

Tags: c, eclipse, macos, gdb, osx-yosemite

after attempting to install gdb on my mac with yosemite (10.10.1) via instructions from [here.](http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/)

I am getting the below error. I codeigned it with no issues, but when I go to run Eclipse and debug I get this error:

`Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 544: (os/kern) failure (0x5).\n (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 544: (os/kern) failure (0x5).\n (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))`

not sure what to do from here. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to code-sign it..
Search for code signing gdb on google...
Still it'll give you other bugs as the last revision of gdb was made in October 2014 before Yosemite was launched..
Its a pain in the ass really!!

Answer (score 0):

I used gdb-apple instead, and it works on Yosemite.